# disable click that calls a javascript function

Tags: jquery

I have a simple menu with this structure:

```
<ul class="navigation">
  <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="javascript:dataTable()">Preview all record</a></li>
</ul>
```

In some cases in my project I need to disable calling dataTable() function when user clicking on this  tag

I am using this

```
$('ul.navigation a').click(function(event){
     event.preventDefault();
});
```

but it doesn't work with me

Answer (score 3):

Try removing the `onclick` HTML attributes instead:

```
$("ul.navigation a").removeAttr("onclick");
```

Comment: the whole site uses ajax to call all pages, so when i remove the onclick, how could i make it work again

Comment: Well, if all the links call `dataTable()`, you can call it explicitly. If you want to support arbitrary Javascript statements, though, you would have to persist the previous value of `onclick` somewhere else (maybe something like a `data-old-onclick` attribute) and invoke `eval()` on it from your event handler.

Answer (score 0):

Try save the value and set the `onclick` attribute with nothing:

```
var tmpVal = $("ul.navigation a").attr("onclick");
 $("ul.navigation a").attr("onclick","");
```

And you can restore the value again :

```
$("ul.navigation a").attr("onclick",tmpVal );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a variable to store whether to call dataTable() or not:

```
onclick="javascript:if(showTable)dataTable()"
```

http://jsfiddle.net/shZFj/1/